# Gradle alternate name for build.gradle and conventions for nested modules

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

Here is a problem I run into.

In Eclipse/STS when I open multiple build.gradle I can't tell what files they belong without looking at the path. (This is same as pom.xml in Maven.)

Is there a way to say have something like below:

```
top-project
        build.gradle
        module-1
            module-1.gradle
        module-2
            module-2.gradle
        .
        .
        module-n
            module-n.gradle
```

In the above module-1 etc. are just names of sub-modules as in one real life example this could be `acme-schema` or `acme-web`

1. How does gradle build work ?
2. More importantly - how does eclipse cope with this during `apply eclipse` / Build Model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common requirement for multi-project builds. It should really be in the user guide. Anyway, you can see an example in [one of my open source projects](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/blob/master/settings.gradle). All you need to do is add something like the following to the *settings.gradle* file in the root of the project:

```
// Change names of build files in sub-projects for easier navigation in IDEs
// and text editors.
renameChildBuildFiles(rootProject)

void renameChildBuildFiles(parentProject) {
    for (p in parentProject.children) {
        p.buildFileName = (p.name - "my-app-") + ".gradle"
    }
}
```

This specific bit of code uses the directory names of the subprojects as the base names of the build files, assuming that all subproject directories are prefixed with "my-app-".

You can use any rule you like in setting the file names of the subproject build files. You don't have to use this one.

Comment: Great idea. Will give it a try. Like the Lazybones name as well.